# Is it possible to determine a WCF binding configuration from the SOAP envelope?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I've generated a WCF client service proxy from a WSDL file, which calls a third-party java web service. Now I need to configure the binding and proxy to call a web method.

However, I only have the below SOAP information, a username and password, and a client certificate. How can I work out what I need to do?

Are there any "reverse this to configuration" apps, or websites that teach the skills required?

I think I am after, "this part of the message, translates to this configuration". Can anyone help?

For the same project, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19431827/198048), so if anyone knows what to ask the third party for, that would also be of help (I'd describe this as "communication information", but I don't think that specific enough).

```
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://etis.ford.com/services/fsa/1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-messagesecurity-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="token-2-1172677451503-9243153">MIICDTCC……..k/j8lARlQ==</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#element-1-1172677451465-2619907">
        <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>k_REDACTED_=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>k_REDACTED_=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="reference-3-1172…..1504-94…25">
        <wsse:Reference URI="#token-2-117…..51503-9…3" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"wsu:Id="element-1-1172677451465-2619907">
        <ns0:list>
            <String_1>k_REDACTED_</String_1>
        </ns0:list>
    </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

The following was generated to my app.config. It doesn't have an exception, but the response I get (in correctly formed XML) contains objects with "nothing" - the actual response looks like a mirror of what I sent.

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                    realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://myurl"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
        contract="wsServiceProxy.ServiceName" name="MyServicePort" />
</client>
```

Request:

```
POST http://www.thehost.com/
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo2dteAUjcNNDmQ28Qhsz8KcAAAAARUELWtvXc06cOf2eOs23AWKlzgCLFBNImUOop7Ho+PoACQAA
SOAPAction: ""
Host: www.thehost.com
Content-Length: 299
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <list xmlns="http://thehost.com">
            <String_1 xmlns="">MyString</String_1>
        </list>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 14:17:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/1.0.0a mod_jk/1.2.31
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo2dteAUjcNNDmQ28Qhsz8KcAAAAARUELWtvXc06cOf2eOs23AWKlzgCLFBNImUOop7Ho+PoACQAA
SOAPAction: ""
host: www.thehost.com
Expect: 100-continue
connection: Keep-Alive, Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 299
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8

<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
        <list xmlns='http://thehost.com'>
            <String_1 xmlns=''>MyString</String_1>
        </list>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: How did you create the proxy? I'm surprised that creating the proxy did not also create the binding configuration.

Comment: I was given a WSDL file that I added as a service reference

Comment: I've pasted it, but I don't think it is working correctly as the response is a mirror of what I sent. This seems to serialise to an instantiated object (different to the one in the response) that has no properties set.

Comment: I expect you would have received a 400 or 500 response if there had been a serious problem with the request. Check with the service author to see what the issue is - I don't think there's a binding issue.

Comment: I will, but that is easier said than done with these big companies and the amount of bureaucracy involved. Going back to the question - how can I tell if this binding is correct for the SOAP I have?

Comment: I think the fact that you got a 200 response implies that the binding is correct.

Comment: I guess I will find out when I have an answer to my other question :)

Comment: What you posted is not a WSDL - at least not any WSDL I'm familiar with.  It looks like the schema for the message.  Second, the format of that schema is SOAP 1.1, so BasicHttpBinding **is** the correct one.  I agree with @JohnSaunders - check with the vendor.  I know the big ones can be a pain, but there are any number of things that could be the issue and it could very well be on their end.

Comment: The answer to your original question is of course NO. You are asking if you can determine the transport used to transmit the content of an envelop.

Comment: @Tim, correct, that isn't the WSDL. This is the message - but I can't test the binding until I sort out my other question first.

Comment: I finally got to the bottom of this (through much guess work): see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20399257/198048 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20349062/198048

Answer (score 2):

Use this custom binding:

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
            <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" includeTimestamp="false"
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                <secureConversationBootstrap />
            </security>
            <httpTransport />
        </binding>
</customBinding>
```

make sure to decorate your contract to sign only:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName=..., ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
```

you will need to configure a service certificate in addition to a client certificate. You (probably) don't have such certificate which is ok, just configure any dummy certificate there (even same one as client).

See [this link](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/12-common-wcf-interop-confusions.html) for more possible error resolution with this scenario.

Comment: I've used certificates before without an issue, we have our own too. If you have a look at my other question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/19431827/198048) you will see the third party doesn't give me a lot to go on. I can't test this until I have that problem solved.

Comment: reference.cs. this is the file of the proxy reference. http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2008/10/who-moved-my-service-reference.html